# Auto-notify when postfix requires TLS?

Tags: centos, postfix, smtp

I've set up postfix on CentOS 7, and configured it to require STARTTLS to accept incoming mail. I've run into a couple instances where a server doesn't, for whatever reason, support TLS encryption, and so never issues STARTTLS and the email bounces. Like it should. But the sender typically just gets an 'undeliverable' message from their mail server, and often is not in a position to know what happened, much less do anything about it.

Since the sending server typically issues `FROM` before being sent the `Must issue a STARTTLS command first` response, the sender's address is potentially available somewhere. Is there any utility to scrape that information and send an auto reply with an explanation and an alternate address or link to a contact form?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may discover sender addresses that submitted unencrypted e-mails by parsing Postfix logs, as @F.sb said. However, in my test environment, I see that Postfix does not log sender address if `smtpd_tls_security_level` is set to `encrypt` (or, in an equivalent manner, `smtpd_enforce_tls` is set to `yes`). Therefore, in order to get sender addresses from logs, `smtpd_tls_security_level` must be set to `may` and unencrypted messages must be rejected during the `RCPT TO` step. In order to achieve that, include `reject_plaintext_session` into `smtpd_recipient_restrictions` and set `plaintext_reject_code` to `530`. For example:

```
# /etc/postfix/main.cf

smtpd_tls_security_level = may
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/postfix/postfix.crt
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = reject_unauth_destination,reject_plaintext_session,permit
plaintext_reject_code = 530
```

---

Then, you can configure `rsyslog` to run a custom executable and supply Postfix logs via `STDIN`. For example:

```
# /etc/rsyslog.d/postfix-logs.conf

module(load="omprog")

template(name="PostfixLogs" type="string" string="%syslogtag% %msg%\n")

:syslogfacility-text, isequal, "mail" action(type="omprog"
    binary="/usr/local/bin/postfix-tls-notify.sh"
    template="PostfixLogs")
```

In that custom executable, you will be able to catch sender addresses through `sed` and send the automatic replies:

```
# /usr/local/bin/postfix-tls-notify.sh

/usr/bin/sed -run 's/^postfix\/smtpd(|\[[0-9]+\]):\s+noqueue:\s+reject:\s+rcpt\s+from\s+[^;]+session\s+encryption\s+is\s+required;\s+from=<([^>; ]+)>.*$/\2/ip' | while read sender; do
    /usr/bin/mailx -s 'Automatic notification' "${sender}" <<'MESSAGE'

    Please, send your inquiries by using https://www.example.com/contact.html

MESSAGE
done
```

---

Note: SELinux may prevent `rsyslog` from sending local messages through `sendmail` (which is invoked by `mailx`). If it happens, configure `rsyslog` to run in permissive mode by issuing the command `semanage permissive -a syslogd_t`.

Comment: Very nice! Just one question - does rsyslogd on CentOS 7 work out of the box with systemd/journald? Or will I have to modify my config to give access? 
EDIT: found this: https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/system_administrators_guide/s1-interaction_of_rsyslog_and_journal which, I think, may answer my question?

Comment: Yes, `rsyslog` works out of the box on CentOS 7 ([and RHEL 7](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/system_administrators_guide/ch-viewing_and_managing_log_files)). By default, `rsyslog` is automatically installed and configured to use `imjournal` module to collect messages from the `journal`.

Comment: Works like a charm!

Answer (score 1):

You can use some postfix log parsers and detect this error then sent a auto reply email to sender.

Consider encryption as an option and better not to enforce it by setting `smtpd_enforce_tls = yes`

Just for Notice enforcing it on a public SMTP server violates [RFC 3207](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3207)

Comment: Your answer does not provide a solution, merely a generic piece of advice. Furthermore, due to security and compliance regulations, this server must not receive unencrypted emails, as messages to this server are considered privileged and protected.